# Prevent methods from being called automatically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In JSF2, is there a way to stop a method from being called automatically? For example, in my bean:

```
public String goToSearchResults() {
    // do all kinds of stuff
}
```

In my `.xhtml` file:

```
<p:commandLink id="srchbutton" action="#{home.goToSearchResults()}">
   <h:graphicImage.../>
</p:commandLink>
```

This method is called whenever the user arrives at my home page, before even specifying search terms. Obviously it's an unnecessary call. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: The given code doesn't do that. You can easily confirm it yourself by copypasting it into a completely blank page in a completely blank playground project with everything set to defaults and most recent versions unless otherwise mentioned in the question ([as anyone else reading this question would (theoretically) do](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)). Perhaps you've in your actual code somewhere a XML-outcommented block with therein the very same EL expression?

Comment: Seems like you're right, it was in an commented out code. Why would it call commented out code?

Comment: Because it only outcomments XML/HTML, not EL. By the way, as general practice, omit EL method parentheses as much as possible, unless you really need to explicitly pass method arguments.